# How to make Dialogflow speech-to-text transcribe letters instead of words

Tags: speech-recognition, dialogflow-es, speech-to-text

I'm building a voicebot in Dialogflow that needs the user to input their user ID and other information in order to prefill the ticket before the user is redirected to the IT-supporter.

BUT the speech-to-text API recognizes the letters in the User ID as words i.e.:
USER: "my user ID is BC56"
STT transcription: "be see 56"

The user ID's always consist of four random ciphers consisting of letters and numbers.

I tried creating a custom entity with apx 200 examples (with automated expansion both on and off) and apx 50 trainingphrases, but it still transcribes the letters as words.

I can use Fullfilment to make my own glossary translating "be=b"; "see=C", but I imagine there must be a better solution making Dialogflow recognizing single letters or the entity format.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue before and I haven't found a solution in the way you're looking for.
You may want to consider getting this information from the user by asking them to type.